# Angular(2+) polyfills: Problems with IE - .includes()

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills

After experimenting a lot, I found out, using `.includes()` in .html template will bug out the application in IE.

e.g. `*ngIf="selectedItems.includes(item)`

I've enabled everything in `polyfills.ts`, still, the IE doesn't read my code properly.

For e.g., when reading `{{aVariable}}` in .html template, it won't display on IE if there's an `includes()`, oddly, it works if I put a `*ngIf="true"` in it's html tag like:

`<span *ngIf="true">{{aVariable}}</span>`

When removing all `.includes()` in the .html template, everything seems to runs fine.

What am I missing, is this possible to solve in polyfills as well?

Comment: which version of IE ?

Comment: @UlrichDohou v11.228.17134.0

Answer (score 3):

Oddly, after tons of searching, I finally found a solution at [github](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7001) after posting this question.

Adding following lines in Polyfills.ts will solve this issue with `includes`:

```
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Hope this will help other.